# Ratio of two unknown line segments using known side

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Point P lies on the side AB of triangle ABC, and the ratio between AP and PB is 1 : 3

The median line from vertex A intersects line segment CP at point Q and side BC at point D

What is the ratio between AQ and QD

The answer should be 2 : 3 but I can't reach it! A vector approach would be optimal and greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: use [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) for $\,\triangle ABD\,$ and transversal $\,CP\,$

Comment: Lovely hint @dxiv! I just learned something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*The most direct solution would use [Menelaus' theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724140/ratio-of-two-unknown-line-segments-using-known-side), as pointed out in a comment already. The following is an alternative way to solve it, per the "vector approach" part of OP's question*.)

By construction:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AP} &= \frac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{4} \\[5px]
\overrightarrow{AD} &= \frac{\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AC}}{2}
\end{align}
\end{cases} \tag{1}
$$

Let $\,\color{blue}{\dfrac{AQ}{QD} = \lambda} \iff \dfrac{AQ}{AD} = \dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda+1} \,$, then:

$$\overrightarrow{AQ} = \dfrac{\lambda \, \overrightarrow{AD}}{\lambda+1} \tag{2}$$

Let $\,\dfrac{CQ}{QP} = \mu\,$, then:

$$\overrightarrow{AQ} = \overrightarrow{AC}+\overrightarrow{CQ}=\overrightarrow{AC}+\dfrac{\mu\,\overrightarrow{CP}}{\mu+1}=\overrightarrow{AC}+\dfrac{\mu\,\big(\overrightarrow{AP}-\overrightarrow{AC}\big)}{\mu + 1}=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AC}+\mu\,\overrightarrow{AP}}{\mu+1} \tag{3}
$$

Equating $\,(2)\,$ and $\,(3)\,$, then using $\,(1)\,$:

$$
\dfrac{\lambda \, \overrightarrow{AD}}{\lambda+1} = \dfrac{\overrightarrow{AC}+\mu\,\overrightarrow{AP}}{\mu+1} \;\;\iff\;\; \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1} \cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AC}}{2} = \frac{1}{\mu+1}\cdot \overrightarrow{AC}+\frac{\mu}{\mu+1}\cdot\frac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{4} \tag{4}
$$

Since $\,\overrightarrow{AB}, \overrightarrow{AC}\,$ are linearly independent, the component-wise coefficients must match in $\,(4)\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
\frac{\lambda}{2(\lambda+1)} &= \frac{\mu}{4(\mu+1)} \\[5px]
\frac{\lambda}{2(\lambda+1)} &= \frac{1}{\mu+1} \\[5px]
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

It then easily follows that $\,\mu=4\,$ and $\,\color{blue}{\lambda=\dfrac{2}{3}}\,$.

Comment: Is this derivation equivalent to proving Menelaus' theorem?

Comment: @martycohen Not as written, but it could easily be made into a proof of Menelaus' or Ceva's theorems.